# Failed to infer type when using Result::map and Box

Tags: rust

Why won't this compile?

```rust
trait T {}

fn f<U: 'static + T, V, E>(f2: V) -> impl Fn() -> Result<Box<dyn T>, E>
where
    V: Fn() -> Result<U, E>,
{
    move || -> Result<Box<dyn T>, E> { f2().map(Box::new) }
}
```

The error message is:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/lib.rs:7:40
  |
7 |     move || -> Result<Box<dyn T>, E> { f2().map(Box::new) }
  |                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected trait T, found type parameter
  |
  = note: expected type `std::result::Result<std::boxed::Box<(dyn T + 'static)>, _>`
             found type `std::result::Result<std::boxed::Box<U>, _>`
  = help: type parameters must be constrained to match other types
  = note: for more information, visit https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html#traits-as-parameters
```

This version is ok:

```rust
trait T {}

fn f<U: 'static + T, V, E>(f2: V) -> impl Fn() -> Result<Box<dyn T>, E>
where
    V: Fn() -> Result<U, E>,
{
    move || -> Result<Box<dyn T>, E> {
        match f2() {
            Ok(result) => Ok(Box::new(result)),
            Err(e) => Err(e),
        }
    }
}
```

In my opinion, `(dyn T + 'static)` and `U` are the same; am I right?

I'm using `rustc 1.39.0-nightly (f0b58fcf0 2019-09-11)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a limitation and I don't know if it will compile one day. The reason is that Rust doesn't know to convert between the two `Result` types, `(dyn T + 'static)` and `U` are totally different things. If this acceptable you can do `f2().map(|x| Box::new(x) as _)`.

The cast will allow the compiler to transform `U` into `(dyn T + 'static)` before put it in the result, we don't need to explicit the cast type the compiler [inference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/types/inferred.html?highlight=inference#inferred-type) will do it for us (on most case).

> A trait object can be obtained from a pointer to a concrete type that implements the trait by casting it (e.g. &x as &Foo)

See [dynamic dispatch](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.30.0/book/first-edition/trait-objects.html#dynamic-dispatch) section of the book (didn't find any information in the new book).

Comment: This could do with a little explaination about what the magic "as _" does. How does the compiler decide what `_` means in this context.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson Hope it's more clear, unfortunately there is not much reference for this problem.

Comment: Thanks, for clearing that up. I knew the compiler would do type inference in a few places, just didn't expect it as part of a `as X`. Looks like a very useful feature. Seems a pity it's not better documented somewhere.