# Matching trait object std::error::Error in iterator

Tags: rust

Here the following code works well :

```rust
use std::collections::BTreeMap;
use std::error::Error;

fn simple_test() -> Result<BTreeMap<String, i32>, Box<dyn Error>> {
    let contents = r#"filed: 1"#;
    match serde_yaml::from_str(contents) {
        Ok(template) => Ok(template),
        Err(error) => Err(Box::new(error)),
    }
}
```

The [Error](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/error/trait.Error.html) trait object match with Error object [serde_yaml::error::Error](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_yaml/struct.Error.html) and all looks good.

But when i try to do the same thing in iterating a list the matching fail.

```rust
use std::collections::BTreeMap;
use std::error::Error;

fn list_test() -> Vec<Result<BTreeMap<String, i32>, Box<dyn Error>>> {
    let list_contents = [r#"filed: 1"#, r#"filed: 2"#];
    list_contents
        .iter()
        .map(|contents| match serde_yaml::from_str(contents) {
            Ok(template) => Ok(template),
            Err(error) => Err(Box::new(error)),
        })
        .collect::<Vec<_>>()
}
```

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:6:5
   |
4  |   fn list_test() -> Vec<Result<BTreeMap<String, i32>, Box<dyn Error>>> {
   |                     -------------------------------------------------- expected `std::vec::Vec<std::result::Result<std::collections::BTreeMap<std::string::String, i32>, std::boxed::Box<(dyn std::error::Error + 'static)>>>` because of return type
5  |       let list_contents = [r#"filed: 1"#, r#"filed: 2"#];
6  | /     list_contents
7  | |         .iter()
8  | |         .map(|contents| match serde_yaml::from_str(contents) {
9  | |             Ok(template) => Ok(template),
10 | |             Err(error) => Err(Box::new(error)),
11 | |         })
12 | |         .collect::<Vec<_>>()
   | |____________________________^ expected trait std::error::Error, found struct `serde_yaml::error::Error`
   |
   = note: expected type `std::vec::Vec<std::result::Result<std::collections::BTreeMap<std::string::String, i32>, std::boxed::Box<(dyn std::error::Error + 'static)>>>`
              found type `std::vec::Vec<std::result::Result<_, std::boxed::Box<serde_yaml::error::Error>>>`
```

I don't understand that error, why the compiler do not check the trait object as the same way as my first test : `simple_test()` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to infer type when using Result::map and Box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59476676/failed-to-infer-type-when-using-resultmap-and-box/59478246#59478246)

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d9833e3681446bc71b587ec2923ee2d5

Comment: Thank you @Stargateur, that exactly solve the problem, but I'm a bit sad that rust do not follow the matching type.